# Rest api to get Docker tag pull counts in arm artifactory

Tags: docker, download, artifactory, pull

Is there any rest api to get the total number of pull counts of a docker image in arm artifactory

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [File Statistics REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileStatistics). This returns the download count as part of the response. You will need to make the request against the manifest.json of a particular image since the way docker pulls work, only the manifest is guaranteed to be downloaded when a client requests an image.